# System sounds open program close program - How To Stop Program From Running/Closing Constantly?

Tags: audio, system-sounds

I like to have some idea what my computer is doing. So I liked it that
windows would let you set a system sound in the setting for open program
and close program. My computer makes endless noises if I don't select none.
I've killed Cortana, uninstalled programs, and tried everything I can think
of but still, although I can't spot anything in task manager, something is
running itself constantly. I've turned off scanning options in my Comodo
Firewall, uninstalled Iobit Malware Scanner program and have very little that
runs at startup and still, I have no solution to a quiet computer that could
be doing anything and I wouldn't have a clue. If anybody has any suggestions
I am anxious to fix this problem so I can hear a laser sound when a program
opens and a buzzer noise when a program closes. I don't like hidden windows,
and programs that take over my machine when I am trying to get serious work
done. Windows has about 42 processes and a long list of services it constantly
runs, is this alot? Any fixes or freeware to help deal with this annoyance would be most
greatly appreciated. Please leave an answer so everyone having this problem
might find peace.

Comment: 42 Processes is quite normal on a Desktop - perhaps on the low side. I have about 125 processes running on my Laptop. There is no harm whatever in processes running - normal. You would have to analyze what processes are running if you are concerned.  You can, if you wish, control sounds by some categories. Control Panel , Sounds.

Comment: Two things to reduce the amount of background processes: disable *specific* services (see http://www.blackviper.com/service-configurations/black-vipers-windows-10-service-configurations/ ) and install a Windows 10 privacy application, such as O&O ShutUpt10. That said, a locked-down Windows may have 100 or more background processes and still be operating about as fast as it can. *Do not* disable Win dows Firewall and Defender, unless you have a good alternative, or you'll be running malware shortly.

Comment: I do have windows firewall and defender turned off, because I use Comodo Antivirus and Internet Security program. My main problem is that something is running, closing, running again so I can't put a sound for open program or close program because all I get is the two sounds constantly. Thanks for the info about services!

Comment: So I guess it's normal for windows 10 to run,quit,run unfindable unseen programs and if open and close program system sounds are useless and have to be turned off to make the computer usable oh well. I suppose there must be some third party freeware that monitors programs and makes sounds. Know any good ones? Thanks microsoft, cortana!